# Protobuf compilation

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, command-prompt, object-detection

While compiling the Protobuf libraries, I ran the following commands from Installation guide-

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

according to the required directory as-

```
(base) C:\Users\HP DV-6>cd C:\object_detection\models\research
(base) C:\object_detection\models\research>C:/object_detection/protoc-3.6.0-win32/bin/protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

I get this error, can anyone help?

```
'C:/object_detection/protoc-3.6.0-win32/bin/protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```